# Is there any difference between spouses chores?

Tags: stardew-valley

Upon getting married, I was pleasantly surprised to learn that my spouse will occasionally do chores: cook food, fill the dog bowl, etc. For my second play-through I read up on the available bachelorettes on the wiki.

The wiki article(s) explain some of the differences between the spouses: what presents they might give you or what food they might cook you. However, it's not clear to me if there's a difference in what farm-related chores they might do. Some individual character articles talk about that husband/wife doing farm work while other's do not, or don't list the same chores, but I'm not sure if that's intentional or just an oversight.

Do the various spouses all do the same farming tasks (watering plants, feeding animals) as each other, or is there a difference depending on which spouse you choose?

Comment: just marry 'em all :v

Comment: well, one of the bachelorettes is like... 9... so I may skip that one...

Comment: wut, one of possible spouse is 9 yo ?

Comment: Jas isn't romancable, unless you're talking mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak from experience, but from what I've seen people say and from my own spouse doing every single chore listed on the wiki, I feel fairly confident saying that every spouse will do the same tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that every spouse does the same chores around the farm.

The long answer is that it is more dependant of freindship level than the person, a spouse at low hearts (for example from gifting to other marriage candidates) will do significantly less work around the farm than one on high hearts.

The other major factor is that some individuals have different routines, for example Harvey still works as the towns doctor, so may still do chores around the farm, but will more often be off at work. In terms of pure mechanics they all do the same work. ConcernedApe did this intentionally to avoid one or other marriage candidates being favoured for 'gamey' reasons, rather than character reasons.

Unfortunately I can't find the forum posts where he stated this for reference.

Comment: Individual routines have nothing to do with chores around the farm.